# Maximum possible integer x, such that sum of every element of array divided by x is not less than k

Tags: arrays, math

> We are given an array of n integers, and a constant value k, can any one 
>       suggest me to find out the maximum possible integer x such that arr[0]/x + arr[1]/x +.. arr[n-1]/x >=k ,

```
-> where '/' is the integer division 
-> sum of all elements of array >= k
-> k is a constant(1<=k<=10^5)
-> 1<=n<=10^5.
e.g. n=5, k=3
arr=[1,1,1,8,8]
answer-> x=4
in something like o(N log N) ?
```

Comment: Is there any limit on the values in the array, even to an order of magnitude? In particular, are they comparable to `n`? I have an algorithm with your desired complexity if they are of the same order as `n`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton 1<=arr[i]<=10^9 , give me your algorithm , it may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that often meets your bound on time efficiency. I assume that your array values are non-negative. The algorithm depends on these facts:

1. Your objective function `arr[0]/x + arr[1]/x +.. arr[n-1]/x` (let's call it `f(x)`) is a decreasing function of `x`. In other words, if `x` increases then `f(x)` will stay the same or decrease.
2. `f(1)` equals the sum of the elements of the array, so `f(1) >= k`. In other words, at `x = 1` the objective function is not below the target value `k`.
3. If `M` is set to the maximum array value, the value of `arr[i] // (M + 1)` is zero, so `f(M + 1) = 0`. In other words, at `x = M + 1` the objective is below the target value `k`.

So we have upper and lower bounds on the value of `x` for a decreasing function. We can therefore do a binary search from `1` to `M + 1` for the value of `x` where

```
f(x) >= k and f(x + 1) < k
```

Only one value of `x` will satisfy that, and a binary search can easily find it. The binary search will take `log(M)` steps. Each step involves one evaluation of `f(x)` which takes `N` steps to use each array member. Thus the overall time efficiency is `O(N log(M))`. If `M` (the maximum array value) is of the order of `N` then that is your desired efficiency. At the limiting values you give for `N` and the array values, we have `M < N^2`, so `N log(M) < 2 N log(N)` and your desired efficiency is still met. If `N` is small and `M` is large, your desired efficiency is not met. (This means an array like `[10^9, 10^9-1]` where `N = 2` and `M = 10^9` which could take `30` steps in the binary search.) This may or may not meet your needs.